Reconfiguring keys in a tsibble (fpp3 package)
I'm working with time series data stored in a tsibble object using the fpp3 package in R.
The data has multiple keys defined based on certain columns.
library(fpp3)
PBS
key(PBS)

However, I need to select only a subset of columns for some analysis/visualization. The issue is that after selecting columns, the tsibble still maintains the original keys even if those columns are no longer included.
> PBS |>
+   select(Month, ATC1, Cost) 
# A tsibble: 67,596 x 6 [1M]
# Key:       Concession, Type, ATC1, ATC2 [336]
      Month ATC1   Cost Concession   Type        ATC2 
      <mth> <chr> <dbl> <chr>        <chr>       <chr>
 1 1991 jul A     67877 Concessional Co-payments A01  
 2 1991 ago A     57011 Concessional Co-payments A01  
 3 1991 set A     55020 Concessional Co-payments A01  
 4 1991 out A     57222 Concessional Co-payments A01  
 5 1991 nov A     52120 Concessional Co-payments A01  
 6 1991 dez A     54299 Concessional Co-payments A01  
 7 1992 jan A     39753 Concessional Co-payments A01  
 8 1992 fev A     54405 Concessional Co-payments A01  
 9 1992 mar A     61108 Concessional Co-payments A01  
10 1992 abr A     65356 Concessional Co-payments A01  
# ℹ 67,586 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

Is there a way using functions in the fpp3 package to redefine the keys after performing column selection operations on the tsibble? I've checked the documentation but didn't see any mention of modifying keys post-transformation.
Help!

Removing key columns with select() will produce an invalid tsibble, unless those key columns were redundant. In this case after removing ATC2, Concession, and Type, there will be duplicate time points for the same time series. You probably instead want to calculate the total cost for each ATC1 with:
library(fpp3)
#> -- Attaching packages ---------------------------------------------- fpp3 0.5 --
#> v tibble      3.2.1          v tsibble     1.1.4     
#> v dplyr       1.1.4          v tsibbledata 0.4.1     
#> v tidyr       1.3.1          v feasts      0.3.2     
#> v lubridate   1.9.3          v fable       0.3.3.9000
#> v ggplot2     3.5.0          v fabletools  0.4.1
#> -- Conflicts ------------------------------------------------- fpp3_conflicts --
#> x lubridate::date()    masks base::date()
#> x dplyr::filter()      masks stats::filter()
#> x tsibble::intersect() masks base::intersect()
#> x tsibble::interval()  masks lubridate::interval()
#> x dplyr::lag()         masks stats::lag()
#> x tsibble::setdiff()   masks base::setdiff()
#> x tsibble::union()     masks base::union()
PBS |> 
  group_by(ATC1) |> 
  summarise(Cost = sum(Cost))
#> # A tsibble: 3,060 x 3 [1M]
#> # Key:       ATC1 [15]
#>    ATC1     Month     Cost
#>    <chr>    <mth>    <dbl>
#>  1 A     1991 Jul 13617917
#>  2 A     1991 Aug 12376201
#>  3 A     1991 Sep 12773459
#>  4 A     1991 Oct 14082325
#>  5 A     1991 Nov 13792933
#>  6 A     1991 Dec 16477982
#>  7 A     1992 Jan 18988760
#>  8 A     1992 Feb 11633278
#>  9 A     1992 Mar 12752540
#> 10 A     1992 Apr 13937039
#> # i 3,050 more rows

Created on 2024-04-28 with reprex v2.0.2

Actually, I don't want to do that. I'm trying to understand the uses of Key variables. I know this should be another post (question). And in fact, when I tried to put together a simple example with just one key variable to be able to answer my question, it became impossible to get rid of the other key variables. My question is what is the use of these key variables. For a moment, I thought it was a way to manipulate several time series databases simultaneously, but I don't think that's true.

Each time series needs to be uniquely identified by key variable(s), in other words there can't be two observations at the same time point with the same combination of key variables. You can only remove key variables if they are redundant. More information here: https://tsibble.tidyverts.org/articles/intro-tsibble.html?q=key#contextual-semantics-index-and-key
